# Simple node.js server to return success or error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajaxform, server-response

This is should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to get it to work as I intended.

I just want a client submit a form with an email address, and node.js server looks up db and return success or error after querying for the submitted email address. As the first step, all I am trying to do is to manually return success or error.

On client side, I am using JQuery and ajaxForm plugin.
On server side I am using connect-form on node.js side.

I can see console.log message from node.js side, but I don't see "SUCCESS" alert on the client side. Instead I see an empty page at localhost:8000. I think the fix would be something simple.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!!

Client-side HTML/JS:

```
<div class="gform">
    <form id="entryForm" action="http://localhost:8000/" method="post">
        <p><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1"> Choice 1</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="choice" value="2"> Choice 2</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="choice" value="3"> Choice 3</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="choice" value="4"> Choice 4</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="choice" value="5"> Choice 5</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="email"> Email Address</p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="form_result">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            dataType: 'json',
            target: "form_result",
            success: goodResult,
            error: badResult,
            timeout: 1000 
        };

        $('#entryForm').ajaxForm(options);
    }

    function goodResult() {
        alert('SUCCESS!');
    }

    function badResult() {
        alert('ERROR!');
    }
</script>
```

Node.js side:

```
var form = require('connect-form'), connect = require('connect');
var server = connect.createServer(
  form({ keepExtensions: true }),
  function(req, res){
    // Form was submitted
    if (req.form) {
      req.form.complete(function(err, fields){
        console.log(fields);
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        res.end();
      });
    } else {
      // Regular request, return error.
    }
  }
);
server.listen(8000);
console.log('Express app started on port 8000....');
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a issue with what's being returned by nodejs. Try changing your ajax function to console.log the response from the ajax call and see what is being returned. That or check the response headers and body in something like chrome's network monitor